# How to show more value in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to buil a query that return the data in this mode:

```
ID_Accesso | Id_Prestazioni
1            1&10&20
2            1&6&60
```

The table are these:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccessiXAttivita](
    [IDAccesso] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDAttivita] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NumeroPrestazioni] [int] NULL,
    [CodiceAttivita] [nvarchar](50) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_EXP_CodiciAttivita](
    [ASL] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CodiceNostro] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CodiceASL] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

I have built this query but this query not show me the result how I want

```
SELECT CodiceNostro,IDAccesso
    FROM AA_V_T_EXP_CodiciAttivita C JOIN AA_V_AccessiXAttivita A
    ON C.CodiceNostro = A.IDAttivita
```

How can I built a query that show me for every IDAccesso, one field with all CodiceNostro?

Comment: Provide sample data how values are stored in these tables for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do It in following:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(ID_Accesso INT, Id_Prestazioni INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (1,1),(1,10),(1,20),(2,1),(2,6),(2,60)

SELECT  ID_Accesso
       ,STUFF((SELECT '&' + CAST(Id_Prestazioni AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @Tbl 
         WHERE ID_Accesso = t.ID_Accesso
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') Id_Prestazioni
FROM @Tbl t
GROUP BY ID_Accesso
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
ID_Accesso   Id_Prestazioni
1            1&10&20
2            1&6&60
```

---

**DEMO**

You can test it at <kbd>**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4176)**</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

`select field1 AS FIELD1,  field2||'&'||field3||'&'||field4 AS FIELD234
 from fields;`

The result will be:

`FIELD1 | FIELD234
 F1     | F2&F3&F4`

Comment: You code not works because I can't know what are the number of fieldX that I hae